# Loading script statically and run when it is loaded

Tags: javascript

I am placing a script as the following:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/blabla.js" type="text/javascript" id="the_script"></script>
```

In jquery I can:

```
$("#the_script").ready(function(){
    alert("loaded")
});
```

**But** I am not using JQuery.
What is the equivalent in vanilla js (native).

here is an example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bmhm65vm/

Comment: Actually, that won't work as you would think in jQuery. No matter what the selector is, the event will always apply to `document`. This is the vanilla equivalent, also applying to all content and not just the script : `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // your code });`.

Comment: Just to demonstrate. http://jsfiddle.net/511n7gc6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `onload` like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/est4dsav/

Here you have all the native options: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 1):

Running a script as soon as a browser loads (meaning before anything else) 
requires you to put the code you want to execute first into the following function:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //Your Code Here.
};
```

The block of code inside of the `window.onload` function will be run FIRST.